# What do I have to type in to get a list of trending venues near me using foursquare API?

Tags: api, foursquare

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question or if this has been answered already as well. I did some digging on this website and couldn't find anything related to my question. I am new to Foursquare API and was wanting to know exactly what I type in the little search bar on the API page when trying to find trending venues within a city (lets say Houston, Texas). I don't know what I have to type in. I did read the documentation and it is confusing. It says to type near but how would I go about typing it in along with the city and state. I also would like to know what I would have to type in the API page to get trending venues near (Houston, Texas) by using Longitude and Latitude and not the near.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did the solution below answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're on the right track. The endpoint (URL) you want to use is:

```
v2/venues/trending
```

You then need to append any parameters to the end of this URL to customize the result. Parameters are appended using the following format:

```
parameterName=Value
```

If you have multiple parameters you join them together using a `&`, like this:

```
parameterName1=Value1&parameterName2=Value2
```

And you join the parameters to the endpoint using a `?`, like this:

```
v2/venues/trending?parameter1Name=Value1
```

You mentioned you want to find trending venues near Houston, Texas. We can use either the `near` parameter, or the `ll` parameter. Like this:

```
v2/venues/trending?near=Houston,Texas
```

or

```
v2/venues/trending?ll=29.8159954,-95.9617495
```

You can [view the result](https://foursquare.com/developers/explore#req=venues%2Ftrending%3Fnear%3DHouston%2CTexas) in the Foursquare Explorer.